# Site URLs using a PHP "pretty url" framework

Tags: php, frameworks, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have been experimenting with the lightweight NiceDog PHP routing framework, which routes like this:

```
R('entries/(?<id>\d+)')
  ->controller('Entries_Controller')
  ->action('show')
  ->on('GET')
```

Now the `.htaccess` file is set up to do this redirect like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My problem is when I want to make a URL to somewhere, it seems impossible to do so.

Say I've requested the page `entries/5`, and on that page I would like to link to another entry `entries/6`:

```
<a href="entries/6">Next Entry</a>
```

This resolves to the address `http://localhost/folder/to/project/entries/5/entries/6`
Not what I want.

The href `/entries/6` would link to `http://localhost/entries/6`
Also not what I want.

To work around this, I created a function to handle this problem:

```
function url($route) {
    return "http://localhost/folder/to/project/$route";
}
```

So I can now write

```
<a href="<?= url('entries/6') ?>">Next Entry</a>
```

which now links to `http://localhost/folder/to/project/entries/6`, which is exactly what I want.

However, I have to do this for **EVERY** in-site link, and it seems like there could be a better solution that doesn't involve an externally created URL.

Is there a "better" way to fix this problem? Is this a "common" problem with PHP frameworks? (It seems it would be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy alternative would be to use <base href="http://example.org/your/project/index" /> in your page templates <head>. But that's basically like having full URLs generated. And yes, it's also valid for XHTML and still in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about NiceDog but other frameworks I have used have a built in function that can convert a route to the corresponding URL.

For example in Symfony this would look something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('entries/show?entry=5') ?>">Link Text</a>
```

The routing system will then reverse resolve this into the URL relative to any root you set in the config.

Comment: That's exactly what I said I wanted to work around in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use:

```
RewriteBase /folder/to/project/
```

in your htaccess file making

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/to/project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't make a difference, because the browser is what resolves the URL.